# Имитация событий нажатия клавиатуры и SendKeys

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь воспроизвести нажатие клавиш. Везде натыкаюсь на SendKeys.
Почему нужно передавать строку, когда для считывания клавиатуры есть KeyDown, KeyPress, KeyUp? Есть ли альтернатива SendKeys, принимающая на входе Keys и тип события?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел все-таки ответ:
[keybd_event - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx)

в результате делаю так:

```
public static class keyImitation
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    public static void KeyDown(Keys key)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    public static void KeyUp(Keys key)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0, 0x2, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Но ведь в MSDN написано, что вместо `keybd_event` нужно использовать `SendInput`? То есть если что-то работает с `keybd_event`, оно должно работать и с `SendInput` по идее.

Comment: @VladD признаюсь, смалодушничал, но не разобрался с INPUT structure. А keybd_event легко прочиталась и влилась в код. Да, пошел по легкому пути...

Comment: С другой стороны, у нас же тут сборник практических знаний? Работает — значит, засчитывается как решение.

Answer (score 1):

`KeyDown` и остальные рядом с ним — это события, которые вызываются при *получении* данных клавиатурного ввода. А `SendKeys` нужно, чтобы этот самый клавиатурный ввод симулировать.

Вы можете вызвать ваш обработчик `KeyDown` вручную, но тем самым вы обманете лишь тот кусок программы, который зависит от **данного** обработчика. А остальная часть программы, которая обрабатывает нажатые клавиши по-другому, будет по-прежнему считать, что никаких клавиш нажато не было.

Comment: спасибо, но вопрос немного в другом - есть ли аналог SendKeys, куда для эмуляции я смогу передавать не строк, а те же Keys. На мой взгляд как-то нелогично - ведь приходится конвертировать сохраненные Keys (в программе пробую повторить действия пользователя) в строку при этом учитывать и Shift и Ctrl  и пр. Или, например, попытаюсь эмулировать перетаскивание мышью с нажатым Control (т.е. нужно передать, что Ctrl удерживается в течении какого-то времени). Как это реализуемо с помощью SendKeys?

Comment: @kvvk: Боюсь, это невозможно. Сейчас попробую найти пруфы.

Comment: @kvvk: Вы можете теоретически использовать [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), но `SendKeys` [под капотом](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/SendKeys.cs,633) делает то же самое.

Comment: отуствие результата тоже результат, буду знать. Спасибо за ссылки, полезно!

Comment: @kvvk: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, в любом случае помогло.